# MS Dynamic CRM Invoke an action within a Dialog

Tags: dialog, dynamics-crm, action

I am trying to run an action from a dialog. According to this is can be done. [Invoke custom actions from a workflow or dialog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn949331.aspx). However my list of steps does not contain an action step. How do I invoke an action from a dialog

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has only been possible to invoke an action from a workflow or dialog since [CRM Online 2015 Update 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98ee20a1-e4b2-4e42-a6ed-583b901507b3(v=crm.7)) (CRM 2016 for on-premise).

> The ability to execute an action from a process was introduced with
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2015 Update 1.

Since it appears you a running a lower version, you will not be able to invoke actions in this way.

Comment: Thank I guess I'll make a plugin to do it